# phpbb when changing the overall style of the style what are all the files that should be altered

Tags: phpbb

I have installed phpbb board in my site.

I want to change the total style and color of the board.

I just want to know what are all the files that I should concentrate on so that finally the total site should look different.

So just drop me the names or references to other resources related to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [article on the phpBB official FAQ](http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/how-to-create-a-style-basics/) describes how to edit the styles for the site.